# Unable to run Bootinfoscript

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I'll try to be as clear as possible by mentioning exactly what i did.I've formatted my windows drive and installed it again and after that installed ubuntu 15.04.The bootloader installation failed so i had to do it manually.I used bootrepair to install grub but after i restarted, grub only showed ubuntu,so i updated grub but then it showed ubuntu and two windows loader.

By browsing on the net i found bootinfoscript should be used to see if anything in that makes sense to me or just use it while asking questions.I downloaded the tar.gz file,extracted it and used the `sudo ~/Downloads/bootinfoscript.sh` command in terminal and i got command not found.

```
    suresh@suresh-pc:~$ sudo ~/Downloads/bootinfoscript.sh
    [sudo] password for suresh: 
    sudo: /home/suresh/Downloads/bootinfoscript.sh: command not found
```

finally coming to the point, i need two questions to be answered

1.How to run the bootinfoscript?

2.How should i remove one of the two windows 7 loaders

Please feel free to mark this as duplicate but please post the link here for the original question/answer that solves my problems

Comment: it is `sudo bash ~/Downloads/bootinfoscript.sh` . It is a bash script.  You may have the Windows boot files in both the Windows boot partition and its main install, so grub2's os-prober finds it twice. Windows files it looks for are bootmgr & BCD.

Answer (score 0):

1. there are several methods to run a BootInfo, see the [Ubuntu community doc about BootInfo.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info)
2. you can use [GRUB-Customizer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134) or [manually edit GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus).